# bokeh layout vertical alignment with buttons

Tags: python, button, row, bokeh, textinput

I am looking for a workaround to an issue in Bokeh.
When you put a button and a text input in a row- they will be un-alighned. This effect happens because the text input has a label and is described here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4817

[screenshot of messed up alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfU6k.png)

Example code:

```
# hello.py 

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, Button, Paragraph

# create some widgets
button = Button(label="Say HI")
input = TextInput(value="Bokeh")
output = Paragraph()

# add a callback to a widget
def update():
    output.text = "Hello, " + input.value
button.on_click(update)

# create a layout for everything
#layout = VBox(children=[HBox(children=[button, input]), output])
layout = column(row(button, input), output)

# add the layout to curdoc
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

set `css_classes` property of the `TextInput`:

```
input = TextInput(value="Bokeh", css_classes=["hide-label"])
```

Add style to `index.html` in templates folder if your application is a folder:

```
<style>
.hide-label label{
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

If the application is a script file, then add a `Div` element with the style sheet.

Comment: I tried the css you suggested and it didn't work. but .hide-label {
    padding-top: 15px;
} did the trick

Comment: BTW, .hide-label {
    display: none !important;
} made the label disappear